# Solving $x^{14} = 14^x$ for $x$

Tags: roots

How can I transform the following equation:

$$x^{14} = 14^x$$

to something of the form

$$x = \cdots$$

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve $x^y \, = \, y^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114453/solve-xy-yx). One of the most popular questions here (and answered hundred's of times already).

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!

Comment: One solution is $1.270640222\ldots$.