# An exponential symmetric system

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponential-function

I have this symmetric systeme with $x,y\in\Bbb R^+$:

$$\begin{cases}
xy=8\\
x^y=y^x
\end{cases}$$

Obviously the solution is the couple $(2,4)$ or $(4,2)$ being the symmetrical system. I have never solved such systems. Is there a method of solution to find **real solutions**?

Comment: FWIW there’s also $x=y=\sqrt{8}$

Comment: @DavidQuinn Is there a method to solve it? Thank you for your comment

Comment: Yes, there is one. Start with the second equation alone, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114453/solve-xy-yx).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you very much.

Comment: The linked dup is about integer solutions, for reals there are more solutions, this was a bit hasted closure.

Comment: @zwim reopen the question :-)

Comment: @DietrichBurde Read the comment of zwim please.

Comment: For real numbers it is also a duplicate, and the first equation then immediately determines  the other real solutions. So it reduces to solving $x^y=y^x$. See for example [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871169/find-all-solutions-of-ab-ba), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793755/given-that-xy-yx-what-could-x-and-y-be).

Comment: What is the reason of two downvotes?