# How to solve this $p^q = q^p$ without logarithms

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$x^y = y^x$ for integers $x$ and $y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/xy-yx-for-integers-x-and-y)

I have found $2^4 = 4^2$ by trial and error,

What is the general solution?  I have no idea of where to start.

Comment: type it into wolfram alpha and then learn about the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of both [$x^y = y^x$ for integers $x$ and $y$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/xy-yx-for-integers-x-and-y) and [Determine the number of solutions of the equation $n^m = m^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199235/determine-the-number-of-solutions-of-the-equation-nm-mn)

Comment: @robjohn how did you find that, sorry that it is a duplication.

Comment: I had answered [Determine the number of solutions of the equation $n^m = m^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199235/determine-the-number-of-solutions-of-the-equation-nm-mn) and that is commented to be a duplicate of [$x^y = y^x$ for integers $x$ and $y$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/xy-yx-for-integers-x-and-y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found the only solution in integers except $p=q.$  For rationals, let $p=\frac ab, q=\frac cd$, both in lowest terms.  Now use the laws of exponents and you will find a one dimensional set of solutions.  Continuity extends this to the reals.

Added:  You want $\left(\frac ab\right)^{\frac cd}=\left(\frac cd\right)^{\frac ab}$.  Think about the primes that might divide $a,b,c,d$

Comment: Could you explain that a more.

Answer (score 1):

For the case when $q/p$ is rational,
let $q/p = r$, so $q = p r$.
Substituting this in $p^q = q^r$,
$p ^ {pr} = (pr)^p$
so, taking the $p$-th root,
$p^r = pr$ sp $p^{r-1} = r$
or $p = r^{1/(r-1)}$
and $q = p r = r^{r/(r-1)}$.

If $r = 2$, $p = 2$ and $q = 4$.

If $r = 3$, $p = 3^{1/2}$ and $q = 3^{3/2}$.

If $1/(r-1) = n$, where $n$ is an integer,
$r = 1+1/n = (n+1)/n$ so $r/(r-1) = n+1$
and $p = ((n+1)/n)^n$ and $q = ((n+1)/n)^{n+1}$.

Note: This is definitely not original with me.

That's all for now.