# Integer solutions for $x^y=y^x$

Tags: number-theory, exponential-function, diophantine-equations

> Let's say we have the equation: $$x^y=y^x$$ what are the solutions when $x,y \in \Bbb Z$ for ${x}\ne{y}$..

The only one I have found is 2 and 4. There are infinite non-integer solutions but I am interested in the integer ones. Also you can find a new definition for $e$ from this equation $e=x^{\frac{y}{xln(y)}}$ and also $log_x(y)=\frac{y}{x}$

Comment: There is $1$...

Comment: Presumably you require $x\ne y$?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199235/determine-the-number-of-solutions-of-the-equation-nm-mn?noredirect=1&lq=1), and others linked to it.