# Proving or disproving: $a^b<b^a$?

Tags: calculus

So, I have two real numbers, and I need to prove or disprove the statement: $a^b<b^a$.

**Note: The question contains real numbers and not parameters. I just don't want you to solve it for me, so I don't reveal the numbers... This is a calculus I question.**

I have thinking about this question for a while, with no clue on what to do.

I thought of defining some functions, and use some theorems we learned...

Any hints on how to deal with those kind of questions will be much appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, it depends on the numbers, but typically, if $b$ is large then $a^b$ will be much larger than $b^a$. For instance, $3^{10}$ is way bigger than $10^3$. If this is an assignment then you should probably approximate whatever numbers you're given by nice ones so that you can work out manually what $a^b$ and $b^a$ approximately are.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/706413/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3186157/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1705690/42969

Comment: Thank you so much guys!
@MartinR, how did you locate those posts?

Comment: One method of solving this is to note that for positive real numbers, $a^b > b^a$ if and only if $\displaystyle a^{\frac{1}{a}} > b^{\frac{1}{b}}$, and a lot of cases can be compared by noting the increasing and decreasing intervals for the function $\displaystyle x\mapsto x^{\frac{1}{x}}$.

Comment: Found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5Ey%20%3C%20y%5Ex%24). – Compare https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/42969 or https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978/42969 on Meta.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the other answers,
the hard case is when
$a < e < b$.

Many years ago,
I proved the following
result in this case:

If
$1 < x < e$
and $e < y < e^2/x$
(i.e., $xy < e^2$)
then
$y^{1/y} > x^{1/x}
$.

I don't know about
$y > e^2/x$.

I've reconstructed my proof
and here it is.

Let
$f(x)
=\dfrac{x^{1/x}}{(e^2/x)^{x/e^2}}
$
with
$1 < x < e$.

The proof shows that
$\ln(f(x))
\lt 0$
for $1 < x < e$.
This reduces to
showing that
$h(z)=(1-z)\cosh(z)-e^{-z}
\lt 0$
for $0 < z < 1$.

As usual,
I'm sure there are
simpler proofs than mine,
which shows that
the coefficients of
$h(z)$
are all negative.

Show
$f(x) <1 $.

$\begin{array}\\
g(x)
&=\ln(f(x))\\
&=(1/x)\ln(x)-(x/e^2)\ln(e^2/x)\\
&=(1/x)\ln(x)-(x/e^2)(\ln(e^2)-\ln(x))\\
&=(1/x)\ln(x)-(2x/e^2)+(x/e^2)\ln(x)\\
&=(1/x+x/e^2)\ln(x)-(2x/e^2)\\
&=(e^{-y}+e^y/e^2)y-(2e^y/e^2)
\qquad x = e^y, 0 < y < 1\\
&=(e^{-y}+e^{y-2})y-2e^{y-2}\\
&=e^{-1}(e^{-y+1}+e^{y-1})y-2e^{y-2}\\
&=\dfrac{2y}{e}\dfrac{e^{-y+1}+e^{y-1}}{2}-2e^{y-2}\\
&=\dfrac{2y}{e}\cosh(-y+1)-\dfrac{2}{e}e^{y-1}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{e}(y\cosh(-y+1)-e^{y-1})\\
&=\dfrac{2}{e}((1-z)\cosh(z)-e^{-z})
\qquad z = 1-y, y = 1-z, 0 < z < 1\\
&=\dfrac{2}{e}h(z)
\qquad h(z)=(1-z)\cosh(z)-e^{-z}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{e}\left((1-z)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^nz^n}{n!}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{2}{e}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}-z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{2}{e}\left(-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{2}{e}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n+1}(1-(2n+1))}{(2n+1)!}\right)\\
&=-\dfrac{2}{e}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{2nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\
&\lt 0
\qquad\text{for } z > 0\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$g(x) < 0$
so $f(x) < 1$.

Therefore,
if $r(x) = x^{1/x}$,
then,
if $1 < x < e$,
$r(x)
\lt r(e^2/x)
$.

Since $e^2/x > e$,
if
$e < y <  e^2/x$,
$r(y)
\gt r(e^2/x)
\gt r(x)
$.

Therefore,
if $1 < x < e < y < e^2/x$,
or $1 < x < e$
and $xy < e^2$
then
$r(y) > r(x)
$.

Comment: Wow thank you for that! 
In my case, both $a<b<e$

Comment: The easy cases are a < b < e and e < a < b. These follow from $x^{1/x}$ having a peak at e.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: If $1 < a < b < e$ then $a^{1/a} < b^{1/b}$ so $a^b < b^a$. The inequality is reversed when $e < a < b$. That is why these are the easy cases. The hard case is when $a < e < b$. My result gives an easy way to decide some of these cases: if $ab < e^2$ and $1 <a < e < b$ then $a^{1/a} < b^{1/b}$ so $a^b < b^a$.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to give a good answer:

First, as the question is stated, the answer is no. Because you are not ordering $a$ and $b$, so you can reverse the tuples, for example $(3,10)$ and $(10,3)$.

Even asking for $b<a$, the tuple (4,2) does not satisfy the inequality because $2^4=4^2$. You can even generate an infinite family of counterexamples with $a=t^{\frac{1}{t-1}}$ $b=t^{\frac{t}{t-1}}$.

However, as the comments above showed, with the condition $e<b<a$ then the inequality holds.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

If we want to show that $a^b<b^a$, then we can raise both powers to the $\frac{1}{ab}$ power (assuming neither value is $0$) to get that our problem is equivilant to showing that

$$\left(a^{b}\right)^{\frac{1}{ab}}=a^{\frac{1}{a}}<\left(b^{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{ab}}=b^{\frac{1}{b}}$$

We now observe that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(x^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x}=0$$

and thus

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{\frac{1}{x}}=1$$

and at $x=0$ we have that $0^{\infty}=0$, and so

$$\lim_{x\to0}x^{\frac{1}{x}}=0$$

Finding extrema of $x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ yields that

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}x^{\frac{1}{x}}&*=\frac{d}{dx}e^{\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{x}}\\
&=e^{\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{x}}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\ln(x)}{x}
&=e^{\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{x}}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{x^{2}}\right)
\end{align*}

and thus our extreme point is when $\frac{d}{dx}x^{\frac{1}{x}}=0$, i.e $\ln(x)=1$, i.e $x=e$. Plugging in $x=e$ to the equation yields $e^{\frac{1}{e}}\approx 1.44>1$, and so this must be a maximum (comparing to endpoints). Thus, if both numbers $a,b$ are on the same side of $e$ then whichever is closest to $e$ has a larger value of $x^{\frac{1}{x}}$. If they are on opposite sides, then you are out of luck with this method.

Comment: Thank you so much!