# $x^y=y^x$: prove that y approaches $1$ as x approaches $\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

$y^x = x^y$

I graphed this function. I have two question about it:

1. Its graph consists of two curves, one of which is $x=y$ and the other curve **looks** like a hyperbola(in the first quadrant) and the curves meet at $(e,e)$. Why $(e,e)$?
2. $y$ value seems to approach $1$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$, how to prove that?

Comment: Zehran, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed by moderators because it is a very low-quality question. Moreover, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Comment: This looks like a decent question to me.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785784

Answer (score 2):

Parametric form for the "almost hyperbola" part is
$$
x = v^{1/(v-1)}
\\
y = v^{v/(v-1)}
\tag1$$
with $0<v<+\infty$.  (See [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_xy_%3D_yx#Positive_real_solutions)) Then take $v \to 0$ and $v \to +\infty$ to find the behavior in the two directions.

Also, to explain $(e,e)$, try to find $v$ in $(1)$ where $x=y$.

Comment: Do not answer very low-quality questions, please.