# Find all distinct integers $(x, y):x\log y = y\log x$?

Tags: number-theory

Find all *distinct* integers $x$ and $y$ that satisfy the following equation.

$$
x\log y=y\log x.
$$

Obviously, if $x=y$, the equation is satisfied.
I found $x=2$, and $y=4$. I think we cannot find all solutions (if there are many).

P.S. The base of the $\log(\cdot)$ is not important.

Comment: $x\log y = y \log x \implies \log y^x = \log x^y \implies y^x = x^y$

Comment: And then, what?

Comment: Look at $f(x) = \frac{\log x}{x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here using some of the $\log$ laws we can find all solution classes.

$$a \log (b)=\log(b^a)$$

and

$$e^{\log(x)}=x$$ shall be all that is required.

$$x\log y = y \log x$$

$$\log y^x = \log x^y$$
$$e^{\log (y^x)} = e^{\log (x^y)}$$
$$y^x = x^y$$

Once we have reached this point, we have a duplicate of [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/xy-yx-for-integers-x-and-y)

Answer (score 1):

For positive real  $x,y$  $$x\log y=y\log x\iff \frac1y\log(y)=\frac1x\log(x)\implies y^{\dfrac1y}=x^{\dfrac1x}$$

Now, show that $f(z)z=z^{\dfrac1z}$ is not constant

Comment: $1^1 < 2^{1/2}$.

Comment: Or, prove that $f(z)=\frac{z}{\log(z)}$ is increasing for $z\ge e$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $x^y = y^x$, with $0 < x < y$ (WLOG).

Let $y= rx$, where $r > 1$.
Then $x^{rx} = (rx)^x$.
Taking the natural logarithm of both sides, $rx \ln x = x (\ln r + \ln x)$.
Dividing by $x$, and rearranging, $(r−1) \ln x = \ln r.$
(Notice that $r = 1$ would be a solution, from which $y = x$.)
With $r > 1$, $\ln x = (\ln r) / (r−1).$
Taking exponentials,$ x = e^{(\ln r) / (r−1)} = (e^{\ln r})^{1/(r−1)}$.
Therefore we have the parametric solution, $x = r^{1/(r−1)}, y = rx = r^{r/(r−1)}.$

If we set $r = 1 + 1/k$, where $k > 0$, we have $x = (1 + 1/k)^k$, $y = (1 + 1/k)^{k+1}$.

Since $r > 1, 1/(r−1) $is positive, and so $x > 1$, and therefore $y > 1$.
(Notice that, if we allow $0 < r < 1, 1/(r−1) $and $r/(r−1)$ are negative, and so again $x$ and $y$ are greater than $1$.  Of course, this must be the case, because $r = a$ and $r = 1/a$ yield essentially the same solution, with $x$ and $y$ swapped.)

We have shown that, for a rational solution, $k$ is an integer; that is $x = [(a + 1)/a]^a$.
If $a > 1$, $a$ and $a + 1$ are relatively prime, and so $[(a + 1)/a]^a$ is a fraction in its lowest terms, with denominator $> 1$, and therefore not an integer.
So the only integer solution is $x = 2, y = 4$.

Hope this helps. Correct me if I'm wrong!

You can refer [here](http://functionspace.org/topic/2341) for more discussion on the same problem!