# Find the all possible real solutions of $x^y=y^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Find the all possible real solutions of $$x^y=y^x$$
$x,y$ both are real numbers.

My attempt:I observed the following solutions

$x=2,y=4$

$x=4,y=2$

$y=x$

Is there any other possible solutions?

Comment: Those are the only positive integer solutions. There will be infinitely many real solutions.

Comment: Consider the equivalent $x^{1/x}=y^{1/y}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: They ask: other than $x=y$.

Comment: The duplicate asks only for integers, but the accepted answer gives a general formula for all real solutions starting with $u\in\mathbb R$. Voting to close.

Comment: @robjohn Sure, just covering all the bases. Also, it's easy to see there are infinitely many solutions since $\log x/x$ has a local maximum where $x=e$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the OP also stated $y=x$ as a solution

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

Applying the logarithm to both sides gives
$$y \log x = x \log y,$$ and rearranging gives
$$\frac{\log x}{x} = \frac{\log y}{y}$$, so we get a nontrivial solution (i.e., one for which $x \neq y$) for any value assumed twice by $f(x) := \frac{\log x}{x}$. More explicitly, if $x$ and $y$ are distinct values such that $f(x) = f(y)$, then by construction we have a nontrivial solution $x^y = y^x$.

The function $f$ is obviously continuous, and

1. has a single root at $x = 1$,
2. is strictly increasing on $(0, e)$ and strictly decreasing on $(e, \infty)$,
3. has a unique maximum of $\frac{1}{e}$ at $x = e$, and
4. has limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} f = 0$.

We can thus conclude that the values $f$ takes on twice are precisely those in $(0, \frac{1}{e})$. Given such a value, it is generally difficult to find its two preimages explicitly*, but nonetheless we can parameterize the solutions as
$$(x, y) = \left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{u}\right)^u , \left(1 + \frac{1}{u}\right)^{u + 1}\right).$$

See [$x^y = y^x$ for integers $x$ and $y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/xy-yx-for-integers-x-and-y) for much more.

*In closed form, anyway, we can write down solutions in terms of the Lambert-W function, which appears on this site much more than it does in "real life"...