# How do you solve $xy=8$ and $x^y=y^x$?

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

I know answers are $4$ and $2$ but can't solve this.

Comment: Are you searching  natural solutions?

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379653/proving-x-2-y-4-is-the-only-solution-to-xy-yx?noredirect=1&lq=1), proving $x=2,y=4$, too.

Comment: For real numbers, $x=y=\sqrt 8$ is also a solution

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate, because the question does not specify that $x$ and $y$ are integers while the questions linked to do.  As Andrei has observed, there is another solution if we drop the restriction to the integers.

Comment: It is not written, but probably meant integers, otherwise the remark" I know answers are $4$ and $2$" is not correct, since we have also $x=y=\sqrt{8}$ for real numbers. So I do think it is a duplicate.