# Are there any other solutions to $x^y = y^x$, $x \neq y$, $x, y \in \mathbb C$?

Tags: arithmetic

As you know, $x = 2$, $y = 4$ is the only solution in integers. Well, also $x = 4$, $y = 2$ if you want to be a smart aleck about it.

But what if you expand the search to include $x$ and $y$ that are rational, or irrational, or imaginary, or complex? Are any other solutions to be found, keeping only the restriction $x \neq y$?

What I have done to try to solve it: just some queries on Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Rational solutions may be found through parametrization of the solution.

Comment: There are a huge number of solutions in the real. $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ has a maximum when $x=e$ and as $x\to 1$, $f(x)\to 1$ and as $x\to \infty$, $f(x)\to 1$. This means for any $a$ with $1<a<e^{1/e}$ we have two values, $x<e$ and $y>e$ so that $x^{1/x}=a=y^{1/y}$, or $x^y=y^x$.

Comment: See the answers of [$x^y = y^x$ for integers $x$ and $y$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/xy-yx-for-integers-x-and-y)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a standard parameterization:

Let
$y = rx$.
Then
$x^y = y^x$
becomes
$x^{rx} = (rx)^x$.

Taking $x$-th roots,
$x^r = rx$
or
$x^{r-1} = r$
or,
finally,
$x = r^{1/(r-1)}$.

From this,
$y = rx
=r^{1+1/(r-1)}
=r^{r/(r-1)}
$.

Put in any value of $r$,
you will get
an $x$ and $y$ satisfying
$x^y = y^x$.

Note:
My answer here
([Are there real solutions to $x^y = y^x = 3$ where $y \neq x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664284/are-there-real-solutions-to-xy-yx-3-where-y-neq-x))
shows that the smallest positive real value
of $z$ such that
there are distinct $x$ and $y$
such that
$x^y = y^x$
is
$z = e^e
\approx 15.15426224
$.

This is why
$2^4 = 4^2 = 16$
works.

Comment: Alright, I just tried it with $r = 3$ and $r = i$, it checks out. That's enough for me tonight. See you tomorrow.

Comment: And it should be noted, the famous $x = 2$, $y = 4$, comes from $r = 2$.