# An equation in Z/nZ

Tags: number-theory

The question is about the equation
$$ x^y\equiv y^x \mod n$$ where $x,y\in \mathbb N_{\geq 2}$.

How can you find if the equation admit a solution in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for a given $n$?

Comment: You can certainly check all pairs $(n,m)$, since there is only finitely many of them...

Comment: But other than that, I think this has already been answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/xy-yx-for-integers-x-and-y

Comment: I am not sure what the equation even means, since if $x\equiv a\pmod{n}$ and $u\equiv b$, we do not necessarily have $ x^y\equiv a^b\pmod{n}$.

Comment: @MTurgeon The link you gave me doesn't answer it, because i'm looking at it in Z/nZ and that's what make it difficult for me. The first answer you gave is obviously right, but it isn't what i'm looking for. I'm more interesting  in a method to find if the equation admit a solution for a given n.

Comment: @AndréNicolas The equation means that $x$ and $y$ are both elements of $Z/nZ$, and the equation is looked from $Z/nZ$.

Comment: What does $x^y$ mean in this context? Note that $2^3\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, while $2^6\not\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. But $3$ and $6$ are "the same" modulo $3$.

Comment: To elaborate a bit on what @AndréNicolas is saying, elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are not integers, they are equivalence classes of integers.  $2$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$; instead it is $[2]=\{2,5,8,11,\ldots\}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks to your comments, i edited the post. I hope what i meant is clearer now. Please let me know otherwise.

Comment: @ElioJOSEPH Since you already know from MTurgeon's link that $x^y = y^x$ admits a solution, you don't need any method to find if $x^y \equiv y^x \pmod n$ admits a solution for a given $n$, because the answer to that is always "yes".  If you care about more than just "yes", make your question more specific.

Comment: An interesting example let $x = k_1\phi(n)$ , $y = k_2\phi(n)$ , where $\phi(n)$ is Euler's totient function then $x^y = x^{k_2\phi(n)} \equiv 1\ mod\ n$ and $y^x = y^{k_1\phi(n)} \equiv 1\ mod\ n$. In cases where $\phi(n) \lt\lt  n$.

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc8m1.png) are all results for $2\le x<y\le8,$ and $n\le\max(x^y,y^x)+1.$ The case $x^y=y^x=16$ is omitted, for obvious reasons.