# Find all the ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x^y=y^x$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find all the ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x^y=y^x$.

So the only ones that i find are when $x=y$ such as $(1,1)$ because $1^1=1^1$.
However, I'm not very familiar with ordered pairs?

Any help?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/xy-yx-for-integers-x-and-y