# Commutators and associators of positive integer exponents

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation

There is a pair $(2, 4)$ for which $2 ^ 4 = 4 ^ 2$. I wonder if there is another such pair $$(n, m): n ^ m = m ^ n$$ It almost obvious that is not. But I failed to prove it.

The question is: does one studied a commutator and associator of ^ operation? Where can I read about it? Is there another such pair? pairs?

Comment: Hint:  look at the function $f(x)=\frac {\log x}x$.

Comment: If positive real numbers are allowed, we have infinite many non-trivial solutions, but for positive integers , the only non-trivial pair is $(2/4)$

Comment: @lulu Is it known whether there is another non-trivial solution in positive rational numbers ?

Comment: Looks like even on real numbers no non-trivial solutions.

Comment: m ^ n = exp(n * ln(m))
n ^ m = exp(m * ln(n))
so
m ^ n = n ^ m => n * ln(m) = m * ln(n) => f(m) = f(n), where f(x) = ln(x) / x

Comment: but... f(x) is monotonic

Comment: @vlad9486 Increasing for $x\le e$ and decreasing for $x\ge e$. Consider for example the pair $(1.7649219\cdots /5)$

Comment: Yes, you are right, the first implication is incorrect.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9505/265452).