# proof that (2,4) is the only natural solution to $x^y=y^x$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to prove that $(2,4)$ is the only natural solution to $x^y=y^x$.
I tried to prove by defining $d=\gcd(x,y), x=d*s,  y=d*r$ for some $s$, $r$.
Using some algebra, I got that s must be equal to 1. I don't know how to continue from here.

My steps:
${ds}^{dr}={dr}^{ds} ->$
$d^rs^r=d^sr^s ->$
$d^{r-s}s^r=r^s ->$
there for $s|r^s$, and because $\gcd(s,r^s)=1$ must be $s=1$.

Comment: What about $(x,x)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Note that $(4,2)$ is also a solution, as well as $(x,x)$ for all natural $x$. I assume you want $x \neq y$, but you should state this explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: we have $x^y=y^x \iff {\ln x \over x} = {\ln y \over y}$ and consider  $f(x)={\ln x \over x}$, which has a maximum at $x=e$.

Comment: An interesting approach. If I got it right, the point is that $x$ and $y$ must lie on opposite sides of $e$ leaving darn few alternatives to check :-) It seems to me that [Michael Lugo used a similar idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10996/11619). Anyway, it is obvious that you came up with this on your own so +1. I would give another +1 for leaving a suitable amount of work for the OP, but I cannot :-/