# Is $x^x$ unique over the positive rationals?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is the function $f(x) = x^x$ unique over the positive rationals? That is, do there exists two different positive rational numbers $x$ and $y$ so that $x^x = y^y$ ?

Comment: I think you mean "injective" by "unique".

Comment: Yes, $x=1/2$ and $y=1/4$, and infinitely many more.

Comment: @ProfessorVector As the OP asks for pairs of **rationals**, I wonder how one can come up with "infinitely many more" cases.

Comment: @Mohsen Shahriari Just there are infinitely many pairs of rationals $(x,y)$ with $x^x=y^y$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Could you provide more examples? It is not clear for me that there are more rational solutions. What I know is that the only solution of the form $x = 1/a, y =1/b$ with $a, b\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ is $(1/2, 1/4)$.

Comment: This question has been changed so much as to be unrecognizable, and to invalidate the existing answers. Please don't do that, you should revert your question so that the answer makes sense, and then you can ask your new question in a new post.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a family of such rational solutions:
$$
x = \left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^{m}, \quad y = \left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^{m-1}
$$
for integers $m \geq 2$.

---

How to get these solutions: assume that $x = b/a, y = c/d$ with $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(c, d)=  1$. Then the equation $x^x = y^y$ gives that the prime factors of $a$ (resp. $b$) should coincides with $c$ (resp. $d$). Also, setting $a = p_{1}^{e_{1}} \cdots p_{r}^{e_{r}}, b = q_{1}^{f_{1}}\cdots q_{s}^{f_{s}}, c = p_{1}^{e_{1}'}\cdots p_{r}^{e_{r}'}, d = q_{1}^{f_{1}'}\cdots q_{s}^{f_{s}'}$ we can prove $e_i' / e_i = f_i' / f_i = bc/ad$ for all $i$, so that $y = x^t$ for some $t\in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$. From this, we have $x = t^{-(1/(t-1))}$, and $t = (m-1)/m$ makes $x, x^t \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: And these are in fact **all** the solutions. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/xy-yx-for-integers-x-and-y). Note that letting $ u = \frac 1 x $ and $ v = \frac 1 y $, $ x ^ x = y ^ y $ is equivalent to $ u ^ v = v ^ u $.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the idea of @ProfessorVector. The resulting pairs should be the same as given by @SeewooLee.

Consider the form $y=x^r$ and suppose $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $r>1$ without loss of generality.

Claim that if $n:=\frac1{r-1}\in\mathbb{N}$, then
$$x=r^{-n},\,y=r^{-rn}$$
is a pair in need.

At first, by $rx^{r-1}=1$, we know that
$$y^y=x^{rx^r}=x^x.$$

It is clear that $x\in\mathbb{Q}$. For $y$, we note that
$$y=x^r=r^{\frac{r}{1-r}}=\frac1r\left(\frac1r\right)^n\in\mathbb{Q}.$$
This proves the claim. $\square$

From this result, we know that $r=2,\,\frac32,\,\frac43$... could be
possible choices, in which cases $(x,y)=(\frac12,\frac14),\,(\frac49,\frac8{27}),\,
(\frac{27}{64},\frac{81}{256})$...