# Equation $a^a=b^b$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Here's the problem:

Find all pairs of rational numbers $(a,b)$ such that $0<a<b$ with $a^a=b^b$.

Using some calculus, I was able to find that $0<a<\frac{1}{e}<b<1$, and I also found one solution
$(a,b) = (\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2})$. I thought it would be the only solution, but I couldn't prove it.
How can I go further and solve this problem?

Comment: It's not the only solution: $(a,b)=(\frac{8}{27},\frac49)$ works.

Comment: Writing $b=ax$ for some $x>1$ and taking logs, we can solve for $a$ and $b$ in terms of $x$ and parameterise the solution by $a=x^{\frac{x}{1-x}}, b=x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$. Since $x=b/a$, we know $x$ is rational, so an equivalent problem is to find the rational $x>1$ for which $x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$ is rational. Letting $x=(n+1)/n$ for $n$ a positive integer, we have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Interestingly enough, there seems to be a close connection to a cousin problem $x^y = y^x$, however, I am still in progress to figure it out mathematically... Nonetheless, have play around on Desmos: (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cqejfjupdm)

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029626/what-are-all-real-solutions-of-equation-xx-yy-what-about-integer-solution ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Write $b=ax$ for some $x>1$. Then $x=b/a$ so $x$ is rational.

Then taking logs, we get
$$a\log a=b\log b=ax\log(ax)\implies \log a=\frac{x\log x}{1-x}
\implies a=x^{\frac{x}{1-x}}, b=x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$$
since $x\neq1$ and $a\neq0$.

Since $x$ is rational, it suffices to find the values of $x>1$ for which $x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$ is rational.

We claim that the only such values of $x$ are $x=\frac{n+1}{n}$ where $n$ is an integer.

We may write $x=1+\frac1n$ where $n\in\mathbb{Q}$, $n>0$. It is easy to see if $n$ is a positive integer that $x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$ is rational. If $n$ is not an integer, write $n=p/q$ where $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ are coprime with $q>1$. We have $x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=\left(\frac{p}{p+q}\right)^{p/q}$. Hence $p$ and $p+q$ must be $q$th powers.

No two $q$th powers can differ by $q$ since for positive integers $u,v,q$, we have by the Binomial Theorem,
$$(u+v)^q-u^q=qu^{q-1}v+\ldots+v^q>q\,.$$
Therefore, if $n$ is not an integer, $x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$ is not rational, so the only rational solutions are given by
$$a=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}, b=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n, n\in\mathbb{Z}^+.$$

Comment: Interestingly, $a,b$ can be rewritten as $a_n= (1-\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}$ and $b_n=(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^n$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n =\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = \frac{1}{e}$ which connects with the observation of OP that $a<1/e<b$.

Comment: It is clear from your proof that if $x$ is of the form $\frac{n+1}{n}$, then $n$ needs to be an integer; but is there a reason why $x$ needs to be of that form? Without that condition the two exponents $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $\frac{x}{1-x}$ would not be integers; does that suffice to rule out any such solutions completely?

Comment: @A.J. $x$ is a rational number greater than $1$, so there is a positive rational number $n$ such that $x=1+\frac1n$ .

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks; that's the link I was missing.

Answer (score 8):

**A Sequence of Solutions**

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3731473), all the points where $x^y=y^x\iff x^{1/x}=y^{1/y}\iff (1/x)^{1/x}=(1/y)^{1/y}$ are given when $x=t^{\frac1{t-1}}$ and $y=t^{\frac t{t-1}}$. This gives $a$ and $b$, where $a^a=b^b$ when $a=t^{\frac1{1-t}}$ and $b=t^{\frac t{1-t}}$. If we set $t=\frac{n-1}n$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
a_n&=\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^n\tag{1a}\\
b_n&=\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^{n-1}\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
which are rational if $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and
$$
{a_n}^{a_n}={b_n}^{b_n}=\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^{n\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^n}\tag2
$$

---

**Monotonic Convergence**

Furthermore, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245) it is shown that $\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^n$ is increasing and $\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^{n+1}$ is decreasing. Taking reciprocals and substituting $n\mapsto n-1$, we get $a_n=\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^n$ is increasing and $b_n=\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^{n-1}$ is decreasing. That is,
$$
a_n\lt\frac1e\lt b_n\tag3
$$

---

**Completeness**

We wish to show that the solutions given in $(1)$, with $n\in\mathbb{N}$, are all the rational solutions.

If both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are rational, then $\frac{n-1}n=\frac{a_n}{b_n}\in\mathbb{Q}$, and therefore, $n=\frac{b_n}{b_n-a_n}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $n=\frac pq$ where $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$ and $(p,q)=1$. $\text{(1a)}$ becomes
$$
a_n=\left(\frac{p-q}p\right)^{p/q}\tag4
$$
[Bezout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) says there are $c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $cp+dq=1$. Since $a_n$ and $\frac{p-q}p$ are rational,
$$
a_n^c\left(\frac{p-q}p\right)^d=\left(\frac{p-q}p\right)^{1/q}=\frac uv\tag5
$$
where $u,v\in\mathbb{N}$ and $(u,v)=1$. Since $0\lt\frac uv\lt1$, we have $0\lt u\lt v$.

$(5)$ implies $p=v^q$ and $p-q=u^q$. Since $u\ge1$ and $v-u\ge1$, we have $v\ge2$ and
$$
\begin{align}
q
&=v^q-u^q\tag{6a}\\
&=\underbrace{\ (v-u)\ \vphantom{\left(q^1\right)}}_{\ge1}\underbrace{\left(v^{q-1}+uv^{q-2}+\dots+u^{q-1}\right)}_{\ge 2^q-1}\tag{6b}
\end{align}
$$
$q\ge2^q-1\implies q=1\implies n\in\mathbb{N}$.