# Rational solutions to $a^b=b^a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, exponentiation

I know that the only positive integer solution to $$a^b=b^a$$ is $a=2$ and $b=4$, but what about rational solutions, what examples are there?
I did some work and found that for example if

$$\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)^{\LARGE\frac{f}{g}}=\left(\small\frac{f}{\normalsize g}\right)^{\LARGE\frac{c}{d}},$$

then $c^{df}=f^{cg}$ and $d^{df}=g^{cg}$.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4029626/42969, in particular the last paragraph in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4029652/42969.