# Solutions of $x^{y} = y^{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am attempting to find solutions to $x^y = y^x$.

I have been trying to find solutions to this equation for quite some time now, and using all the math (and common sense) I know, I arrived at one possible non trivial solution, $x = 4, \;y =2.$

Are there other **solutions** to this equation and if there are how do I find them?

Comment: So $x^y=x$? Is that your equation? The solutions are x,y=1 and some ugly y=imaginary answers with ln(x)

Comment: It’s $x^y=y^x$.

Comment: Blackpenredpen solved this: [video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PI1NeGtJo7s)

Comment: Please use MathJax. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: This [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304191325/http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Sved50816668.pdf) might be useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$x^y = y^x$ for integers $x$ and $y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/xy-yx-for-integers-x-and-y)  Though the question asks about integer solutions, the accepted answer provides the general solution.

Comment: Nice find, @Arturo!

Comment: Using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) you can get a general solution as
$$
y x^{-\frac{y}{x}} =1 \implies -\frac{\color{blue}{y}}{x} \ln(x) \color{blue}{e^{-\frac{y}{x} \ln(x) } }= -\frac{\ln(x)}{x} \implies \boxed{y = -\frac{x}{\ln(x)} W\left(-\frac{\ln(x)}{x} \right)}
$$
which can even be extended to obtain complex solutions.

Comment: In the next comment, I'll post a live Sage / Python script that solves for $m$ in $x=(1 + 1/m)^{m+1}$, without using the Lambert W. It's optimized for $x>e$, but it will work for $x>1.2$ or so. It uses Newton's method, and gets its initial approximation via $e\approx(1+1/m)^{m+1/2}$. (The Sage function n() just gets a numeric approximation of its arg; Sage works with symbolic expressions, when it can).

Comment: [$x^y=y^x$ script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVkEFqwzAQRfc-xWAEnrHdBpV2ExBklWO4hMZJDJYcVItKLr17R1ZiJ7OQNG--9D_6vgw_eBl1j0VR7DtzBKG3AoTwCmUlN5qaX13JPyEyIdyd1eCVC7w2QYXGC8GXibJdZ8bWHr7G7Nie4BO9eqdtBlwTKOiHM3qaW8ctethAS83bTDQTyQAdvIBcVVHkGr1oDD6okuw0WOigM2AP5tzix80y1tVyItS0AHuz0Qvpo4t95XDyiqsweeHEPn0yi7bz0dIaL8ap0osJhnvmbPXPdV6DriF3vDt6nAQm4Yn4Mv5TIB54KCE1z3fK9JOsMBhYMxH9A4Pdazs=&lang=sage)